# Definition of Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the meaning of **objects** in a vector space?

> **Definition:** A vector space is a nonempty set **V** of **objects**, called vectors, on
>   which are defined two operations, called addition and multiplication
>   by scalars, subject to the ten axioms...

Can entries of a vector be anything other than real or complex numbers?

Comment: Important vector spaces have functions as elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector is an object.  It does not need to have "entries"; this is a property that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has, but not most other vector spaces.

For example, the set of all real polynomials in the variable $t$, denoted $P(t)$, is a vector space.  There are no entries; a vector looks like $1+2t-3t^5$.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. Anything that can be "added" in a sensible way can be considered a vector. For example polynomials, and in particular, functions. In quantum mechanics this difference is almost ignored entirely; then functions are commonly referred to as "vectors".

Comment: To call something a vector, we usually require more than being able to add them. In particular, there are plenty of abelian groups that cannot be made into vector spaces.

Comment: I understand, I tend to "abuse" inverted commas like I did above.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be clearer if the definition instead read:

> **Definition:** A vector space is a nonempty set **V**, whose elements we will call vectors, on
>   which are defined two operations, called addition and multiplication
>   by scalars, subject to the ten axioms...

As pointed out in the other answers, the vector space can be absolutely any set on which you can define the required operations.

Comment: Technically, it cannot be just any set. Not all sets can be given the structure of a vector space (as only certain finite cardinalities are possible). But I do like this reformulation.

Comment: Sorry, I might've been a little over-enthusiastic. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The vectors in a vector space are objects. These objects can be many different things. They can be ordered pairs with elements from a field $F$, sequences with elements from a field $F$, $m$ x $n$ matrices with entries from a field $F$, the set of all function from $S$ to $F$ denoted by $f(S,F)$ where $S$ is any non-empty set and $F$ any field, the set of all polynomials with coefficients from a field $F$ where $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ and $n$ is a non-negative integer and each $a_k$, called the coefficient of $x^k$, is in $F$. As you can see, there are many vectors that we can study in relation to vector spaces. In fact, everything I have just stated is a vector space with the operations of addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this definition:

> **Definition:** A vector space is a nonempty set **V** of **objects**, called vectors, on
>   which are defined two operations, called addition and multiplication
>   by scalars, subject to the ten axioms...

The axioms guarantee that $V$ under addition is an abelian (i.e., commutative) group. The set of scalars has to be a *field*. This means that among scalars the usual algebraic rules valid in ${\mathbb Q}$, or ${\mathbb R}$, or ${\mathbb C}$ apply. But there are other examples of fields, as explained in algebra or number theory courses.

Now to the question of "entries". In building a general theory of vector spaces the notion of *dimension* comes up. When a vector space $V$ over  some scalar field $F$ has dimension $n\in{\mathbb N}$ then for all practical purposes (i.e., after choosing a basis) $V$ can be viewed as the set of all $n$-tuples $(\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_n)$ from elements of $F$. The $\xi_k\in F$ are the "entries" you spoke about. It is true that for vector spaces connected with physical or technical situations the scalar field $F$ tends to be $={\mathbb R}$ or $={\mathbb C}$.